# How to get python3 pypy on centos 7

Tags: centos7, centos6, rhel, pypy, rhel7

i need pypy compatible to python3(for django2.0) on centos 7

Portable version and ubuntu version not work, centos have only 2.7 pypy
question is how to get python3 compatible result?

I got 2.7-compatible tree when i get source like this

```
hg clone http://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy pypy
pypy get-pip.py
/usr/lib64/pypy-5.0.1/bin/pip install virtualenv
pypy -m virtualenv /tmp/pypy27_venv/
source /tmp/pypy27_venv/bin/activate
pip install -r pypy/requirements.txt
cd /usr/src/pypy/pypy/goal
pypy ../../rpython/bin/rpython --opt=jit
```

After build compleate i get

```
/tmp/usession-default-19/build/pypy-3-centos7/bin/pypy 
Python 2.7.13 (0873ec79aa36, Jan 19 2019, 13:33:23) [PyPy 6.1.0-alpha0 with GCC
4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found.

Docs not say, but for python3 compatible tree need get pypy3-v6.0.0-src.tar.bz2 from

https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/

```
cd /usr/src/
wget -c https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy3-v6.0.0-src.tar.bz2
tar -xjf pypy3-v6.0.0-src.tar.bz2
pypy=/usr/src/pypy3-v6.0.0-src/

yum -y install gcc make libffi-devel pkgconfig zlib-devel bzip2-devel \
sqlite-devel ncurses-devel expat-devel openssl-devel tk-devel \
gdbm-devel python-cffi\
xz-devel

yum install pypy -y
pypy get-pip.py

/usr/lib64/pypy-5.0.1/bin/pip install virtualenv

pypy -m virtualenv /tmp/pypy27_venv/
source /tmp/pypy27_venv/bin/activate

pip install -r ${pypy}/requirements.txt

cd ${pypy}/pypy/goal
pypy ../../rpython/bin/rpython --opt=jit
```